# Nested arrays of methods/data

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, methods, nested

I have a question regarding nested arrays of objects.

I’m writing a simple objective c program (I’m a beginner) and I was wondering whether it is advisable to structure an array in such a way that not only are all the individual batting scores be logged (data), but also methods embedded in the nested arrays could be used to interrogate the this data.

For example the line below is easily readable (even for those who are not cricket fans!)

```
Team1.Over[2].BowlNumber[3].score = 6
Team 1 scored a 6 during the 3rd bowl in the 2nd Over.
```

I would also like to do something like the following where I can use a method to interrogate the data. The method line below would just cycle through the scores within BowNumber[] and total the scores up

```
Total =  Over[2].TotalForAmountForOver()
```

I could set up and manage all the arrays from within main() , but its much easier to read if I can embed as much as possible within the structure.

Is this a common approach?
 
Haven't seen many examples of fairly complicated embedded arrays of data and methods….

Answer (score 0):

You'd easily be able to achieve this by making `Over` cant `Bowl` classes that each wrap an NSMutableArray object. e.g.

```
- (void)getOverNumer:(int)index {
  return [overs objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

You'd then access it like this:

`[[team1 getOverNumber:2] getBowlNumber:2].score = 6;`

`int total = [[team1 getOverNumber:2] totalForAmountForOver];`

You'd implement `totalForAmountForOver` as a method within your `Over` class.